# SQL operate between two values by date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset with date and number_clients in which I need to make the difference between one day and another.

Example of the desired output:

```
date       number-clients     difference
21-05-2021      30                 0
22-05-2021      27                -3
23-05-2021      38                11
24-05-2021      32                -6
```

Do you know how can I perform this? I use BigQuery.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Get the preceding value using LAG()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT x,y, number_clients,
      number_clients - LAG(number_clients, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY x, y ORDER BY date) AS difference
    FROM table
    ORDER BY x, y, date
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `LAG()` analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT date, number_clients,
       number_clients -
           LAG(number_clients, 1, number_clients) OVER
           (ORDER BY date) AS difference
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does work indeed. The only issue here is that I have more inputs shown in select so when run my whole query the result is a mess. There is a way to make the difference taking into account just number_clients and date? Thank you!